# Does Ciphertext policy ABE support search operation on encrypted data

Tags: abe, data-privacy, searchable-encryption

Basically CP-ABE (or attribute based encryption) allows end-users to encrypt the data with desired access control structure. I was investigating the how to do keyword-search on encrypted data given the user has appropriate keys (may be like trap-door/delegation keys).

Interestingly the paper "Multi-user Attribute Based Searchable Encryption" tries to solve the same problem which is published in 2013 in IEEE. [link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6569090)  - (I think access to paper requires IEEE access, sorry for that)

Edit:

After some investigation found that:
"Enhancing Data Privacy in the Cloud", Yanbin Lu and Gene Tsudik, [Iacr link](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/158.pdf) proposes search leveraging on Predicate encryption as a function. - I am not sure if CP-ABE is related to predicate encryption and the search operation can be generaized for CP-ABE as well.

I am sure this problem might have been tackled much before also, so seeking some help from experts regarding *Data search operation on encrypted data using CP-ABE scheme*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. you may consider re-editing it.  Are you asking if cp-abe supports searchable encryption by giving away appropriate keys ?

Comment: In theory , ABE, PBE are further generalized as Functional encryption. So is your question whether FE (or its variants) could be used for Searchable encryption ? if then how ?

Comment: ABE is the especial type of Predicate Encryption(PE) and PE is the especial type of Functional Encryption. The difference between PE and ABE is that in ABE the vector of attributes (or policy) is clear but in PE this is hidden.